# Function Returns multiple values but read only some specific values

Tags: function, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":"
read one two three four<<<"$(foo)"
```

In this i want only one, two, and three values and not four. What can I do?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're really trying to accomplish given the code. Would you mind elaborating a bit? Are you taking in user input? What is the user going to put in, the delimited string or 4 separate inputs? What do you want to output and in what format are you wanting to output it?

Comment: As is, you'll end up with `one=this`, `two=that`, `three=the`, and `four=other`. What do you *want* instead? (Note, also, that restricting the change to `IFS` to this call to `read` is better than setting it globally: `IFS=: read one two three four <<< "$(foo)"`.)

Comment: i want to read only three values not fourth one and i am getting fourth value combine in third one ,but i don't want fourth value